# How to show symbolic links like LS -al?

Tags: c, printing, symlink, ls

I've created a rough program that prints out a similar prompt to that of ls -al using C. While it works nearly perfectly besides not being able to dynamically print out the directory that wasnt able to be opened as no arguments are given its just run in the currently directory so i figured `.` would suffice but if theres a better way to dynamically do such let me know. I was wondering how can you print out the symbolic links to a file if there are any like is displayed below.

**CODE**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *mydir;
    DIR *thedir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat myStat;
    struct passwd *pwd;
    int size = 0;
    struct tm lt;
    char buf[1024];
    char length[100];
    long width;
    struct group *gf;
    int len = 0;
    mydir = opendir("./");
    thedir = opendir("./");
    if(mydir!= NULL){
    while((myfile = readdir(thedir)) != NULL){
        lstat(myfile->d_name, &myStat);
        size += myStat.st_blocks;
        width = (long)myStat.st_size;
        sprintf(length, "%ld", width);
        if(len < strlen(length)){
        len = strlen(length);
     }

    }

    printf("total %d\n", size/2);
    closedir(thedir);

    while((myfile = readdir(mydir)) != NULL)
    {

        lstat(myfile->d_name, &myStat);
        if((lstat(myfile->d_name, &myStat) ) == 0){
            pwd = getpwuid(myStat.st_uid);
        }
        gf = getgrgid(myStat.st_gid);
        time_t t = myStat.st_mtime;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timebuf[80];
        char timebuf2[80];

        strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%F", &lt);
        strftime(timebuf2, sizeof(timebuf2), "%R", &lt);
        printf( (S_ISDIR(myStat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (myStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        printf(" ");
        printf("%ld ", myStat.st_nlink);
        if(pwd != 0){
            printf("%s %s %*ld %s %s %s\n", pwd->pw_name, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
        }else  {

            printf("%d %s %*ld %s %s %s\n", myStat.st_uid, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        } 
        }
    closedir(mydir);
    }else{
        printf("ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied");

    }


}
```

**Current Output**

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    0 2019-04-04 17:11 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    0 2019-04-04 17:11 file1.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 travis travis 4096 2019-04-04 17:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 travis travis 4096 2019-04-04 17:11 .
-rwxrwxrwx 1 travis travis    9 2019-04-04 17:11 link1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 travis travis    9 2019-04-04 17:11 link2
```

**Desired output**

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    0 2019-04-04 17:11 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    0 2019-04-04 17:11 file1.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 travis travis 4096 2019-04-04 17:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 travis travis 4096 2019-04-04 17:11 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 travis travis    9 2019-04-04 17:11 link1 -> file1.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 travis travis    9 2019-04-04 17:11 link2 -> file2.txt
```

Comment: _readlink_  is the function you want, see my answer

Comment: you may also want to check if the file is a symbolic link or not: S_ISLNK

Comment: so if S_ISLNK returns not null then how do i append to show the link? can you perhaps show me an example as an answer?

Comment: I edited my answer to add a proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program you look at `st_nlink` but it concerns the *hard link* (`ln ...`), not the *symbolic links* (`ln -s ...`)

Look at *readlink* for the path you want to write

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <unistd.h>
>
>   ssize_t readlink(const char *pathname, char *buf, size_t bufsiz);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   readlink()  places  the  contents  of the symbolic link pathname in the
>   buffer buf, which has size bufsiz.  readlink() does not append  a  null
>   byte  to buf.  It will (silently) truncate the contents (to a length of
>   bufsiz characters), in case the buffer is too small to hold all of  the
>    contents.
> ```

For instance replace

> ```
>    if(pwd != 0){
>        printf("%s %s %*ld %s %s %s\n", pwd->pw_name, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
>    }else  {
>
>        printf("%d %s %*ld %s %s %s\n", myStat.st_uid, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
>        printf("\n");
>    }
> ```

by

```
    if(pwd != 0){
        printf("%s %s %*ld %s %s %s", pwd->pw_name, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
    }else  {
        printf("%d %s %*ld %s %s %s", myStat.st_uid, gf->gr_name, len, (long)myStat.st_size, timebuf, timebuf2, myfile->d_name);
    } 

    char linkname[PATH_MAX];
    ssize_t r = readlink(myfile->d_name, linkname, PATH_MAX);

    if (r != -1) {
      linkname[r] = '\0';
      printf(" -> %s\n", linkname);
    }
    else
      putchar('\n');
```

Comment: Okay ill try to implement now, never used readlink before. If i wanted to insert it into the loop will it cause an error if there isnt a symbolic link?

Comment: @BretHasel is you use it on a non symbolic link _readlink_ will returns -1 and _errno_ will be set with _EINVAL_

Comment: could i perhaps request you for an example? Thinking that i encapsulate my print statments with an ifstatement involving readlink and then if -1 print how i am now else print with readlink. But how does readlink append the pathname?

Comment: @bruno the st_nlink is totaly fine how its used.

Comment: @x539 yes, I said because I supposed the associated print was to debug/search case of symbolic links ;-)

Comment: Thank you, i understand a lot better now and working it in right now.

Comment: last question i have though, how do i change that list bit of the permissions to an l for link?

Comment: @BretHasel fine, note I did not changed your `if(pwd != 0) printf(...); else printf(...)` in only one `printf("...", (pwd != 0) ? ... : ..., ...)` to show better the change, but is simpler to use only one printf ;-)

Comment: @BretHasel to add the 'l' just call readlink earlier to detect that case

Comment: oh okay so call it earlier before theyre added and if true then add l else continue